# Find the probability that $1984!$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be a permutation of the numbers $1,9,8,4$ and let $n = (10a+b)^{10c+d}$. Find the probability that $1984!$ is divisible by $n$.

I was told this could be solved by casework on $a$ and using Fermat's Little Theorem. For example, if $a = 1$, there are $6$ possibilities; if $a = 4$, there are $4$ possibilities; and if $a = 8,9$, there are $5$ possibilities.
How do I use Fermat's Little Theorem to get this?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem appears to be irrelevant, but casework is easy enough...using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to get the order of the desired primes.

Comment: @lulu Can you show how to do the casework?

Comment: I have posted a case by case solution below.  It is easy enough, step by step, but it is clearly somewhat error prone.  I advise checking it over.

Answer (score 1):

Basic procedure:  There are $12$ possibilities for $\overline {ab}$.  For each, we factor the two digit number $\overline {ab}$ and for each prime $p|\overline {ab}$  We compute the valuation $v_p(1984!)$ using Legendre's formula:

$$v_p(1984!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac {1984}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$

Note:  of course this is a finite sum, despite appearances.

So, let's go through the $12$ cases. What follows is elementary but, clearly, somewhat error prone.

Case 1:  $\overline {ab}=19$

$19$ is prime and we easily compute $v_{19}(1984!)=109$.  Now, $109$ is larger than any two digit number so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 2:  $\overline {ab}=18$

$18=23^2$  and we easily compute $v_{2}(1984!)=1979,\;v_{3}(1984!)=988$.  Both of these are larger than any two digit number )or twice any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 3:  $\overline {ab}=14$

$14=2\times 7$  and we easily compute $v_{2}(1984!)=1979,\;v_{7}(1984!)=328$.  Both of these are larger than any two digit number )or twice any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 4:  $\overline {ab}=49$

$79=7^2$  and we easily compute $v_{7}(1984!)=328$.  This larger than twice any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 5:  $\overline {ab}=48$

$48=2^43$  and we easily compute $v_{2}(1984!)=1979,\;v_{3}(1984!)=988$.  These are larger than four times any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 6:  $\overline {ab}=41$

$41$ is prime  and we easily compute $v_{41}(1984!)=49,$.  This is less than either $98$ or $89$, hence $\fbox 0$.

Case 7:  $\overline {ab}=89$

$89$ is prime  and we easily compute $v_{89}(1984!)=22$.  This is greater than $14$ but less than $41$ hence $\fbox 1$.

Case 8:  $\overline {ab}=84$

$84=2^2\times 3\times 7$  and we easily compute $v_{2}(1984!)=1979,\;v_{3}(1984!)=988,\;v_{7}(1984!)=328$.  These are larger than two times any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 9:  $\overline {ab}=81$

$81= 3^4$  and we easily compute $v_{3}(1984!)=988$.  This larger than four times any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 10:  $\overline {ab}=98$

$98=2\times 7^2$  and we easily compute $v_{7}(1984!)=328$.  This is larger than two times any two digit number) so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Case 11:  $\overline {ab}=94$

$94=2\times 47$  and we easily compute $v_{2}(1984!)=1979,\;v_{47}(1984!)=42$.  Now $42$ is larger than $18$ but less than $81$ hence $\fbox 1$.

Case 12:  $\overline {ab}=91$

$91= 7\times 13$  and we easily compute $v_{7}(1984!)=328,\;v_{13}(1984!)=163$.  These are larger than any two digit number so both possible exponents work, hence $\fbox 2$.

Combining we get $$\boxed {2+2+2+2+2+0+1+2+2+2+1+2=20}$$

As there are $4!=24$ permutations, the final answer, barring arithmetic error, is $$\frac {20}{24}=\boxed{\frac 56}$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Thanks!  I can never remember how to extend those brackets.  Perhaps now I will (unlikely, but one can always hope).

Answer (score 0):

The following PARI/GP program determines the permutations for which
$1984!$ divides the given number :

```
? q=0;x=[1,9,8,4];for(j=1,24,p=numtoperm(4,j);a=x[p[1]];b=x[p[2]];c=x[p[3]];d=x[
p[4]];if(Mod(1984!,(10*a+b)^(10*c+d))==0,q=q+1;print(q,"      ",a," ",b,"
",c," ",d)))
1      1 9       4 8
2      1 8       9 4
3      1 8       4 9
4      1 4       9 8
5      1 4       8 9
6      9 1       8 4
7      9 1       4 8
8      9 8       1 4
9      9 8       4 1
10      9 4       1 8
11      8 1       9 4
12      8 1       4 9
13      8 9       1 4
14      8 4       1 9
15      8 4       9 1
16      4 9       1 8
17      4 9       8 1
18      4 8       1 9
19      4 8       9 1
20      1 9       8 4
?
```

The failing permutations are :

```
? q=0;x=[1,9,8,4];for(j=1,24,p=numtoperm(4,j);a=x[p[1]];b=x[p[2]];c=x[p[3]];d=x[
p[4]];if(Mod(1984!,(10*a+b)^(10*c+d))<>0,q=q+1;print(q,"      ",a," ",b,"
",c," ",d)))
1      9 4       8 1
2      8 9       4 1
3      4 1       9 8
4      4 1       8 9
?
```

So, $20$ out of the $24$ permutations are sucessful. Therefore, the probability that $1984!$ divides the number is $\frac{5}{6}$.